# Replace multiple patterns once at a time with python

Tags: python, loops, replace, split, match

so what i wanna do is basically i have a list of urls with multiple parameters, such as:

```
https://www.somesite.com/path/path2/path3?param1=value1&param2=value2
```

and i would want to get is something like this:

```
https://www.somesite.com/path/path2/path3?param1=PAYLOAD&param2=value2
https://www.somesite.com/path/path2/path3?param1=value1&param2=PAYLOAD
```

like i wanna iterate through every parameter (basically every match of "=" and "&") and replace each value one per time. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Start with `urllib` to parse the URL and get a list of parameters. Then you can loop through the list, replacing one value each time, then combine them back into a complete URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse
import re

urls = ["https://www.somesite.com/path/path2/path3?param1=value1&param2=value2&param3=value3",
        "https://www.anothersite.com/path/path2/path3?param1=value1&param2=value2&param3=value3"]
parseds = [urlparse(url) for url in urls]
newurls = []
for parsed in parseds:
    params = parsed[4].split("&")
    for i, param in enumerate(params):
        newparam = re.sub("=.+", "=PAYLOAD", param)
        newurls.append(
            parsed[0] +
            "://" +
            parsed[1] +
            parsed[2] +
            "?" +
            parsed[4].replace(param, newparam)
            )
```

`newurls` is

```
['https://www.somesite.com/path/path2/path3?param1=PAYLOAD&param2=value2&param3=value3',
 'https://www.somesite.com/path/path2/path3?param1=value1&param2=PAYLOAD&param3=value3',
 'https://www.somesite.com/path/path2/path3?param1=value1&param2=value2&param3=PAYLOAD',
 'https://www.anothersite.com/path/path2/path3?param1=PAYLOAD&param2=value2&param3=value3',
 'https://www.anothersite.com/path/path2/path3?param1=value1&param2=PAYLOAD&param3=value3',
 'https://www.anothersite.com/path/path2/path3?param1=value1&param2=value2&param3=PAYLOAD']
```

Comment: @FozenOption If the order matters, we can order the parameters by regular expression.

Comment: This somehow only take two parameters at a time, like if there was param3 it would give me param1 and param2 or param1 and param3 or param2 and param3, it's omitting the 3rd parameter, what changes do you suggest to do this

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it:

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse

url = "https://github.com/search?p=2&q=user&type=Code&name=djalel"

parsed = urlparse(url)
query = parsed.query
params = query.split("&")
new_query = []
for param in params:
    l = params.index(param)
    param = str(param.split("=")[0]) + "=" + "PAYLOAD"
    params[l] = param
    new_query.append("&".join(params))
    params = query.split("&")

for query in new_query:
        print(str(parsed.scheme) + '://' + str(parsed.netloc) + str(parsed.path) + '?' + query)
```

Output:

```
https://github.com/search?p=PAYLOAD&q=user&type=Code&name=djalel
https://github.com/search?p=2&q=PAYLOAD&type=Code&name=djalel
https://github.com/search?p=2&q=user&type=PAYLOAD&name=djalel
https://github.com/search?p=2&q=user&type=Code&name=PAYLOAD
```